# Term I've heard on Craigslist by Sellers

Tags: phrase-meaning

People will write in the "gigs" section where they offer different types of jobs usually for cash.  At the end some people write "Must Be Knock".  What does that mean?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the phrase in question is not an English collocation but an error made by a non-native speaker.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Weird, you VTC a question you answered :p

Comment: @user178049 : Not so weird really. The OP deserves an answer, but why leave the question around possibly to confuse future learners?

Answer (score 2):

I believe those are the words of a non-native speaker attempting to direct the reader to use the contact information. Note the spelling and grammatical errors:

```
Please only contact in the bellow email
must be knock here  [Contact Button]
```

a second example:

```
Please only contact in the bellow email, otherwise i can not contact
with you and could not any response of your massage because i use
that email only use for craigslist posting. After posting i will 
open this email so if you want to contact with me then must be knock 
here
```